# Does BTRFS's compress logic apply when defragmenting?

Tags: btrfs, defragmentation

When mounting a BTRFS filesystem with the `compression` option, BTRFS will [selectively compress files depending on whether they are deemed compressible or not](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression#incompressible).

Does this same logic apply when defragmenting? Or does the following force compression?:

```
btrfs filesystem defragment -r -czstd /data
```

```
# btrfs version
btrfs-progs v4.19
```

Answer (score -1):

From the BTRFS Wiki:

> **How can I recursively compress/uncompress a directory (including
>   guessed/forced-compression)**
>
> Uset the btrfs filesystem defrag command, the option -r will process
>   the files recursively in a directory. This is independent of the mount
>   options compress or compress-force, and using the option -c you can
>   set the compression algorithm.
>
> Currently (v4.14), it's not possible to select "no compression", using
>   the defrag command. This may change in the future.